# Pyspark - Dataframe foreach function not works on multiple workers/parallelize

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am running a Spark StandAlone cluster with 1 master and 2 slaves on EC2. The cluster is working. I have a python application which loads data from s3. The code is below:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Example").getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.csv("s3n://bucket-name/file-name.csv", header=True, mode="DROPMALFORMED")
```

Then I applied `.foreach(func)` on df to do some work on each of the row of df:

```
def test_func(row):
    row = modify(row)
    row.save() # just an example

df.foreach(test_func)
```

I have read on the documents and they say the `.foreach()` is already optimized for distributed/parallel processing. However, the test_func is only running on 1 node, please see the log below: (task 3 is the `.foreach(test_func)`)

```
INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 3.0 with 1 tasks
INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 3, 1xx.xxx.xxx.xx2, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 17460 bytes)
INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Launching task 3 on executor id: 0 hostname: 1xx.xxx.xxx.xx2
```

Is there anyway to distribute this `test_func` to multiple nodes/workers in the cluster? Help is really appreciated. Thank you in advance.

******UPDATE******

I have bumped up the data but there is still only 1 task assigned to 1 worker and it takes a lot of time to run the function. 
This is how I run the application

```
./bin/spark-submit --packages com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-pom:1.10.34,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.2 --master spark://ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.internal:7077 examples/src/main/python/test.py --executor-memory 5G --deploy-mode cluster
```

Another thing is even I set the `--executor-memory 5G` but the workers only use 1Gb Ram. Could anyone help me with this? I have been stuck at this for few days. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: This code doesn't explain single task, if that is really the case. There could be simply not enough data for more.

Comment: Hi LostInOverflow, thanks for your comment. This single task needs 3 minutes to complete, if it could be distributed, I think it should be faster? Anyway I'll try with larger dataset to see if there is any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @LostInOverflow:

> This code doesn't explain single task, if that is really the case.
>   There could be simply not enough data for more.

This is correct. After I increase my data to few ten thousands of records, the task gets split and assign to all the executors.